# Why didn't my tag wiki edit appear?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

I posted a question regarding the game Wayward. Since there was no tag for it, I added one and then wrote a tag wiki entry. It was approved (I still see the reputation gain from the accepted edit), but the tag wiki is still empty. [See here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/wayward/info)

When I browse history, I see my edit there: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/161087/revisions

So I got the reputation from an accepted edit, it seems it is the most recent version on the tag wiki, but I can't figure out why isn't it displayed on the tag wiki page.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and blame "caching". That's really odd.

Comment: I can't tell if it's been approved yet, but it's not in my review queue.  I probably skipped it when it first appeared.

Comment: Huh, if you go to the page and click create tag wiki, your content shows up in the edit box.

Comment: @MBr It was [approved](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76189) back in March.

Comment: Yep, I deliberately waited for a bit (well, over a month) to make sure it isn't just stuck in some queue.

Comment: Might have something to do with the lack of excerpt